# SQL-Query gives back 2 returns where it should give back one

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, conditional-statements

I got the following problem:

I got 2 tables:

```
bestia_assets
bestia_servers_specifications
```

In my assets there are a lot of information about used servers by user. For example:

```
- User: 1 - Asset: example.com
- User: 1 - Asset: example.org
```

which is saved in the assets-table.

In the servers-table I store information about the server itself.

Like:

```
- Serverid 33 - FQDN: example.com
- Serverid 33 - IP: 123.123.123.212
- Serverid 34 - FQDN: example.org
- Serverid 34 - IP: 212.212.212.123
```

And so on

Now I would like to get all users that are using the server with the ID 33

My first try:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.userid, s.serverid
FROM  bestia_servers_specifications as s
LEFT JOIN bestia_assets as a
ON a.asset = s.value) as servers
WHERE servers.serverid = 33
GROUP BY servers.userid
```

But this gives me back 2 entries:

```
1: userid NULL serverid 33
2: userid 1 serverid 33
```

So this is not usable for me. How can I get the user that uses an asset which is attached to the server with `serverid 33`?

This is the creation of table `bestia_servers_specifications`

```
CREATE TABLE `bestia_servers_specifications ` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `serverid` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `type` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',        
    `value` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',       
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is the creation of the table `bestia_assets`:

```
CREATE TABLE `bestia_assets ` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userid` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `type` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',        
    `asset` text,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is the content of the assets-table:

[image]

In the server-table there are a lot of information about different servers like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you please update the question to include specifications for the two tables (columns, keys)? It's hard to tell how they're designed and how they relate.

Comment: Hi jpw, I added some more information in my post. I hope it's getting clear what I want :-) In a nutshell: I would like to get the users which are using an asset which is linked (by assettable.asset = servertable.value) to a specific server (for example with ID 33)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting two rows is that you are using a left join and the join won't match anything for the row with type = 'ip4' and this will give you a null value for the userid.

The solution would be to limit the type joined to the 'fqdn' since the relation between the tables seems to be asset=fqdn value.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT a.userid, s.serverid
FROM bestia_servers_specifications as s
LEFT JOIN bestia_assets as a
ON a.asset = s.value
WHERE s.serverid = 33 AND s.type = 'fqdn'
```

Using a `left join` will get you those servers that have no matches in the assets table - if you only want the servers that have matches, just omit the `left` keyword.